# Azure VPN Client - "The service has not been started"

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn

I downloaded and installed Azure VPN Client, but when I run the application, I immediately get an error: The service has not been started. After importing the settings, nothing happens either. [image]

I tried all the options, it works on other PCs where OS Windows 10 Pro is installed. On my PC is Windows 10 Enterprise, version 22H2.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and vpn connected successfully***

Try to Re-install azure vpn client from [here](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/azure-vpn-client/9NP355QT2SQB?hl=en-in&gl=in)

Using the **`openvpn`** protocol and Azure Active Directory authentication, I can connect to your Azure virtual network gateway.

Make sure to grant admin consent for your organization. Enables the Azure VPN application to log in and access user profiles and select the account that has the Global administrator role like below.

[image]

***Go to azure active directory -> properties -> use Tenant ID***

[image]

- Use tunnel type as Openvpn and copy the Tenant with **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AzureAD TenantID>/`**
- Audience as default public **`41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4`**
- Issuer as -   **`https://sts.windows.net/<AzureAD TenantID>/`**

And, then download the Azure VPN Client profile configuration package Extract the downloaded zip file and unzip on azure vpn folder try to upload like below

[image]

***Azure VPN client is connected successfully with same version.***

[image]

***Reference*** :
[Configure Azure AD tenant and settings for P2S VPN connections| Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant)

Comment: The problem is harder than it looks. Azure is fully configured and has been working for all my colleagues for a long time, but it does not work only for me. The only difference is that they have Windows 10 pro